# Get all the string elements after first space

Tags: r, split

If I have a with character elements divided by space, how can i create 2 vectors ,one of everything before the space and one after the space. One important thing is that some characters have multiple spaces

Example: say my vector is called vec1

```
(head) vec 1
'rrrt rrr' 'tttt   gg'    'tt pp' 'hhhh      k'
```

As you can see some words are divided by multiple spaces, I would like to have 2 vectors like this

```
head(vector1)
'rrrt' 'tttt' 'tt' 'hhhh'
head(vector2)
'rrr' 'gg' 'pp' 'k'
```

As you can see the first vector has everything before the first space and the second vector has everything after the space but without the actual spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `sub` with pattern `\\S+` (one or more non-white space) followed by one or more white space to remove the prefix or we can remove the white space followed by non white space to remove the suffix.

```
sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', vec1)
sub("\\s+\\S+$", '', vec1)
```

Or use `read.table` to convert this to a `data.frame` with two columns and then extract those columns

```
d1 <- read.table(text= vec1, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
v1 <- d1[,1]
v2 <- d1[,2]
```

Or another option is `strsplit` to split it to a `list` and then extract the `list` elements.

```
lst <- strsplit(vec1, "\\s+")
v1 <- sapply(lst ,`[`, 1)
v2 <- sapply(lst, `[`, 2)
```

#### data

```
vec1 <- c("rrrt rrr", "tttt   gg", "tt pp", "hhhh      k")
```